# Flagged comment td lacks "comment-actions" class, making indentation too wide

Tags: bug

A comment I flagged under an answer of mine, lacks the `comment-actions` class on its containing `<td>`.

This makes its indentation a bit too large:

[image: Flagged comment]

Adding the class back on the `<td>` (`div[class="comments"] > table > tbody > tr[class="comment"] > td`) fixes this:

[image: Flagged comment (fixed)]

Edit 2015-08-14: it's back again, observed on one of the comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013349/windows-10-explorer-crash-errrr). Refreshing the page a few times made the issue disappear.

Edit 2016-05-18: it's back. Again.

Edit 2017-01-13: [back again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341500/large-gap-at-the-start-of-a-comment?noredirect=1#comment432289_341500).

Comment: Seems to be fixed again, though the class is still not added to the `<td>`.

Comment: As of 2015-06-23, this issue is [reported to be back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297621/large-gap-in-front-of-flagged-comment?lq=1).

Comment: [It's back again](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341500/large-gap-at-the-start-of-a-comment?noredirect=1#comment432289_341500) - 2017/01/13

Comment: The ["this post"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013349/windows-10-explorer-crash-errrr) is only viewable by 10k+ers (now deleted), and [it was back again today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359286/1415724) but it went back to normal after. Seems we're chasing a phantom.