# Large gap in front of flagged comment

Tags: bug, design

I recently flagged a comment as obsolete, and removed my comments from the thread that it was related to.  After refreshing the page, I noticed a massive gap before the flagged comment:

[image: massive gap]

It's still there on subsequent refreshes.  The answer I flagged the comment on [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31006493/791010).

Comment: Comment is gone now btw :D But the TD width was indeed set to a large value.

Comment: Have had it happen on another one elsewhere as well now.

Comment: 10K rep users: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294233/3049655 . For <10K rep users: "_The "gap" contains the commands that appear on hover (you may still be able to upvote comments you have flagged, although I'm not 100% sure about that). It also contains space for the comment score.By commands I meant the upvote arrow and the flag. It makes sense you cannot upvote a comment you have flagged, and you probably also cannot flag it again, so the first half of the "gap" feels superfluous, but still has to be there for alignment purposes._" - [Frédéric Hamidi](http://goo.gl/n67Tnk)

Comment: @CoolGuy For us mere <10k users, we can't see that one :)  From the URL though, appears to be the same thing - any reason given for it's deletion?

Comment: Should I post an answer? And @JamesThorpe , I posted Frederic's comment here. Screenshot from the above post I linked to: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tB24J.jpg

Comment: @CoolGuy Is this definitely the same gap we're talking about?  I can understand a "normal" size gap on flagged comments, but in my post above, it's abnormally large.  It also doesn't happen on all flagged comments, so far I've only seen it on comments that are by themselves and not part of a larger chain.

Comment: @JamesThorpe , I added the screenshot from my post I linked to in my earlier comment. Seems to be the same issue. And FYI, I'm the owner of that post I linked to. I can undelete it if you want to see it.

Comment: @CoolGuy So the answer to your dupe was that it's by design?  Still seems very odd to me...

Comment: @JamesThorpe , There isn't any answer. [That](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297621/large-gap-in-front-of-flagged-comment?noredirect=1#comment210686_297621) was a comment.

Comment: @CoolGuy ok - out of interest, why delete it?  Seems like a legitimate issue to me

Comment: @JamesThorpe I felt that it is a minor issue...

Comment: @CoolGuy Oh it is, I'm not expecting this to be ringing alarm bells in SE headquarters :)  Still be nice for it to get fixed to keep the quality high though :)

Comment: Does it happen on other sites in the SE network? If so, maybe meta.SE would be a better place. Or maybe it has something to do with the new navigation?

Comment: Happened for me before, disappeared by itself: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290608/flagged-comment-td-lacks-comment-actions-class-making-indentation-too-wide