# Large gap at the start of a comment

Tags: bug, comments, design

I came across the following issue today where a comment had a large gap at the start of it compared to the normal gap (see the top circle):

> [image: Comment gap]

I believe it happened after I flagged the comment. However, when another comment was added and I clicked "Show 1 more comment" the gap reduced to it's normal size.

Comment: Woops just seen [this bug report](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290608/flagged-comment-td-lacks-comment-actions-class-making-indentation-too-wide) with the same issue. However, that has had no activity on it so will leave this open unless it is required to be duped...

Comment: It's preferred to close as duplicate, even if the target doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: @Stijn Okay will do