# There is more space at the left of a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

(See the Update further down).

I just noticed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267900/php-files-not-uploading-in-windows-server#comment81486524_47267900) now, that contains a big space between the left edge and the start of the comment.

Is this a bug <strike>and related to it being upvoted</strike>?

As compared to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267828/automatically-re-paginate-pdf-via-php#comment81486621_47267828) in another question that does not have that additional space.

Here are two screenshots:

With space:

> [image]

Without space and not upvoted (least, not at the time of my posting this):

Sidenote: that comment was edited. The screenshot for this was taken when it was not edited.

> [image]

This is happening for me on Firefox 56.0.2 (Edit: and on Opera) - it wasn't like that before.

## Edit:

I reloaded that first comment and now it appears to have come back to its normal state; here's a new screenshot:

> [image]

---

**So... what happened during that time; goblins?**

## Edit #2:

[It did it again...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272580/my-sessions-arent-working-correctly#comment81496137_47272580), screenshot and this doesn't matter if a comment was upvoted/flagged, since [I posted a quick test comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272580/my-sessions-arent-working-correctly#comment81496785_47272580) under it.

## Screenshot:

> [image]

## Update:

The comments in this question [My sessions aren't working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47272580/1415724) still have a large gap after revisiting it and that is odd in itself.

## Screenshot:

> [image]

While comments in this one [What does FALSE : TRUE do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47293792/1415724) don't have that gap.

> [image]

**Stranger** is that when I click on the "add a comment", the comments no longer have a gap and move over to the left and this has been confirmed by another member here on Stack, telling me he also saw that same (odd) behaviour.

> [image]

Comment: No repro with Firefox 56.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: @Stijn *Hm...* that's odd.

Comment: I'm curious, where are the upvote and flag icons placed when you hover the comment?

Comment: @Stijn They're placed one on top of each other and to the left of the comment. First the arrow to upvote, then the flag under it.

Comment: I reproduced it in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer on Windows 10.

Comment: Did you flag it? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290608/flagged-comment-td-lacks-comment-actions-class-making-indentation-too-wide

Comment: @CodeCaster I didn't flag it, maybe someone else did.

Comment: On Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303246

Comment: I felt *absolutely mental* while scrolling down this post and thinking "this is the end of it! No, this is the end! No, this..."

Comment: @the4kman *lol!* - Yeah, I have to admit that I "too" got caught in that. Let me see what I can do to fix this. I'll reping when I have. Thanks for your input on this.

Comment: @the4kman I edited, it's the best I can do for now. The screenshots are important and show the different behaviours.

Comment: Me too (Chrome on Mac). I've been seeing it on other sites: [this one with multiple comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvX9N.png) (IPS meta),
[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXKpu.png) until 
[somebody added a comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exWJH.png) (one of the educator sites), and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATe4g.png) on a site with a theme (ELU).

Comment: @Laurel It's rather odd that the comments under a question doesn't have the extra gap, while comments under an answer does. And this seems to be alternating. I don't know if and when they'll do anything about it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I posted a [dupe question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359592/first-comment-on-question-is-indented) just now, didn't find this one while searching. Linking here because it's still happening and I've got some extra info there (and animated gifs!)

Comment: @Fred-ii- in [the example link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47272580/1415724) under the update section, I see the gap in all comments in the page; both question and answer.

Comment: @Gimby Seems like it's going to get fixed in the next build; see the (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

I recently removed an innocent little line from the site's CSS, because I couldn't figure out what its purpose was. Now we know, I guess. (In its defense, the code line had a comment saying something like "this needs to be here". In *my* defense, that line was 8 years old and not very specific on the "why").

The difference between your comment sections **with** and **without** extra space is *whether or not there is at least one comment that wraps to multiple lines*. If there isn't, then the table layout algorithm will allocate extra space to the left column (where the upvote controls etc. reside), because the right column (where the text is) doesn't need the space.

This whole thing by the way is a good example of how table layouts are an endless pain (I'm actually working on ripping those out at the moment; you can follow my commit messages for this project in [this twitter thread](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/928670140484472832)).

Comment: Ah, sweet! So, that 8 year old phantom has finally met its maker ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, for now I've brought it back from the dead to fix this bug, but only until I completely tear this whole haunted house down.

Comment: Gotta love a good mystery though. It keeps us all on our toes ;-)

Comment: @balpha thanks for the update! Going with flex or grid layout as a replacement?

Comment: @TylerH Grid with a couple of fallbacks -- it needs a feature that's currently only available in Firefox (and Chrome behind a flag). But once it's in all browsers, we can rip the fallbacks out and end up with a nice clean grid layout :)

Comment: Ahhh... so  you're the dev we should put next to a big red button with "Do Not Press Because Stuff Will Happen!" on it and see how long it takes you then? :p

Comment: Reminds me of this immortal scene from Friends: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WYGdstEVJQ :D

Comment: you read that comment the other way 'round I'm afraid. Apparently it meant to say that the rest of CSS should be removed and only this line "needs to be here". I recommend you to give it a try

Answer (score 2):

This happens even without an upvote on the comment. I've only seen it happen so far on comments that exist as the only comment under the post.

Inspecting the comment's CSS vs other comments on the same page that didn't show the extra space didn't yield any obvious differences. Refreshing does not change it.

I'm on Firefox 56.0.2 on Windows 7.

[image: Extra Space]

Question link with the comment shown above - [Flexbox wont expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269159/flexbox-wont-expand)

Comment: This is something that's happening occasionally, in blurts. I distinctively remember not seeing that extra space; I remember stuff like that ;-) It seems to be an ongoing phantom bug that's never been caught (yet).

Comment: [New/recent comment with that space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272580/my-sessions-arent-working-correctly#comment81496137_47272580) and I've a screenshot if you want it. I'm questioning the minus votes on my question also.

Comment: See my **Update**.