# First comment on question is indented

Tags: bug, comments, design

There's a peculiar formatting issue with comments. The first comment on a question is indented slightly. I've confirmed this on Chrome (latest) and Edge.

The indentation goes away if:

1. There's multiple comments
2. The new comment box is opened (as per image below)
3. The comment is long enough to extend over multiple lines.

---

#### First example:

[image]

#### Second example:

[image]

PS Apologies for the lack of red freehand circles, it's a pain to add them to animated gifs!

Comment: Dammit @rene! I really did look for a dupe before I posted this...

Comment: I know, I know, I'm sorry ...

Comment: At least mine has animated gifs though...

Comment: @DavidG hehe yeah... animations help also :-) they still haven't found that phantom bug yet *lol!* - I've noticed that some posts still have the gap and others don't and seem to be alternating in some rather bizarre way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Feel free to steal them for your question! I've not noticed the comments *not* being indented if the comment is short enough and there's only 1 though. Seems to be (to me at least!) a very reproducible bug.

Comment: @DavidG It's fine David, thanks. If and when I decide to use them, least I'd of already had your blessing ;-) as for what I said above, look in my post and you'll see near the bottom that there are 2 links that show what I mean.

Comment: @rene Maybe it's because that mine contains "space" in the title, as opposed to the word "gap". Then again, and it's been said somewhere that the search method isn't the best and using Google is better. To which is what I used initially before posting my meta post. That's probably why David didn't find anything related to it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I simple remembered you posted it ... so I didn't need to look far or go insane with the search feature ...